# Headset Button as a trigger even the application is in background

Tags: android

I'm creating a `music player` in `android` and I want that when I press the headset button, the song will `play/pause` even if my application is in the background/foreground. I'm using a service class.

How can I trigger the event when the headset button is pressed even if my app is in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Use [the guide](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html). There is a description of hardware buttons usage.